# UITableViewController viewWillAppear

Tags: delegates, uitableview

I have a view controller that is a subclass of UITableViewController. Here is my viewWillAppear:animated method:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{  
    [super viewWillAppear:animated]; 

    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        [fetchedResultsController release];
        fetchedResultsController = nil;
    }

    [self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:nil];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

I am getting confused by seeing the fetchedResultsController being accessed when         [super viewWillAppear:animated] is called. Since super is a UITableViewController, and there is no viewWillAppear:animated method for that class, per se, then its superclass viewWillAppear:animated should be called, right? If that's correct, then the UIViewController class should not be accessing UITableViewController delegate methods. But I see that numberOfSectionsInTableView is getting called. I'm not sure why the call to super viewWillAppear:animated would do this.

So before I explicitly run the peformFetch and reloadData, the table is getting populated. At that time, the data it is being populated with is out of date.

Here is the fetchedResultsController code

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *) fetchedResultsController {
    if (fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = ...
    NSEntityDescription * entity = ...

    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];

    NSSortDescriptor *aSortDescriptor = ...
    NSSortDescriptor *bSortDescriptor = ...

    NSArray *sortDescriptors = ...
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = ...

    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    ...        
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSError *error = nil;

    if (![fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved Error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        abort();
    } 

    return fetchedResultsController;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) specifically describes this behaviour:

> When the table view is about to appear the first time it’s loaded, the table-view controller reloads the table view’s data. It also clears its selection (with or without animation, depending on the request) every time the table view is displayed. The `UITableViewController` class implements this in the superclass method `viewWillAppear:`. You can disable this behavior by changing the value in the `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` property.

Comment: Thanks for help. I generally scroll through the methods in the drop down box, and there is no mention of a viewWillAppear method for UITableViewController. I still don't see how the superclass viewWillAppear applies, so I'm guessing they unintentionally left it out of the docs.